# Intellisense indicates that form doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I opted to copy my web code from one page different page just because it made more sense in the scheme of things to have it be the 'Default.aspx' page. I figured no biggie... copy all but the top line and make some minor alterations to the aspx page then copy all of the aspx.cs page and should be golden.

Wasn't that clean to my surprise!

First had to redefine my sql connections (not a big deal).
But the thing that really has be in a bit of a quandary is Intellisense has gone stupid on me regarding the FormView used on the page.

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="ARS30InputFrm" DataSourceID="ARFS" DefaultMode="Insert">
```

This is clearly in my aspx page. Data source works all should be fine. But I have an error over on the aspx.cs where I redline on the form name on line three here and the help indicates that it doesn't exist!

```
    protected void ARSControlNumTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox thecontrol = (TextBox)ARS30InputFrm.Row.FindControl("ARSControlNumTextBox");
        if (thecontrol != null)
            Session["CCtrl"] = thecontrol.Text;
    }
```

ie: TextBox thecontrol = (TextBox).... ARS30InputFrm .... is where the error flags.

Any idea's on how to clear this issue? I've tried rebuilding, reloading, but nothing seems to work. This clearly is the name of the form!

Comment: It sounds like you didn't change the type names properly - include the header from both ASPX files (you do not want to have two pages that pretend to be the same type), as well as the namespace and class name from the CS files.

Comment: @Luaan I created a separate project to put the code in for this.

Comment: Is this issue for the FormView only or are other errors? I am not familiar with asp.net but have been tripped up in c# where a reference to the `.cs` file was required in the xaml, worth checking (`<Application x:class` and `StartupUri` in `App.xaml`, `<Window x:class` and `xmlns:local` in WPF form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is not an answer to 'WHY' intelisense went wacko, but I was able to solve the issue by blowing away the aspx and aspx.cs and recreating them as I had done before (about 3 minutes of copy work) and it worked straight up!

It simply must have been something in VS that was glitchy and didn't go down right the first time through. The second time was a charm.

Live and learn...